# Why I can't access the object in my json?

Tags: java, json, servlets

I have this json string, comming from a java script:

```
[{"clientNumber":"33"},{"clientName":"3"},{"clientEik":"3"}]
```

when I get it inside of my servlet, here is what I'm doing:

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(URLDecoder.decode(mainData, "UTF-8"));
dataObj.put("data", jsonArr);
```

Now it looks like:

```
{"data":[{"clientNumber":"33"},{"clientName":"3"},{"clientEik":"3"}]}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the `clientNumber` by:

`dataObj.getString("clientNumber")`

BUT it is bombing me with an exception:

`org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["clientNumber"] not found.`

Why I can't access it? I know that I'm missing a really small part, but I can't make my mind and find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `data` field is an JSONArray. You need to get the element by index, pls ref to the code:

*UPDATE:*

use `getJSONObject(index).getString(key)` to access data:

```
try {
        String data = "[{\"clientNumber\":\"33\"},{\"clientName\":\"34\"},{\"clientEik\":\"35\"}]";

        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8"));
        JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject();
        dataObj.put("data", jsonArr);

        JSONArray jsonarr = dataObj.getJSONArray("data");

        String clientNumber = jsonarr.getJSONObject(0).getString(
                "clientNumber");
        System.out.println(clientNumber);
        String clientName = jsonarr.getJSONObject(1)
                .getString("clientName");
        System.out.println(clientName);
        String clientEik = jsonarr.getJSONObject(2).getString("clientEik");
        System.out.println(clientEik);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: it works, but only for the 1st record - I can't get `clientName` by using `jsonarr.getJSONObject(0)` or `jsonarr.getJSONObject(1)`

Comment: @Slim, I have updated the code and tested in my local. Pls try it.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `dataObj` is an array of key value pairs. So you need to get the array first and iterate through the array and get the value of `clientNumber`.

Use `dataObj.get(0).getString("clientNumber");`

Answer (score 1):

With Gson Library you can do something like this:

```
    public MyClass {

       public void doSomething() {
            JsonArray array = new JsonParser().parse(mainData).getAsJsonArray();        
            JsonObject obj1 = array.get(0).getAsJsonObject();   
            MyData data = new Gson().fromJson(obj1.toString(), MyData.class);        
            System.out.println(data.getClientNumber());        
       }

      class MyData {
        private String clientNumber;
        public String  getClientNumber() {return clientNumber;}
        public void setClientNumber(String  clientNumber) {this.clientNumber = clientNumber;}
            public String toString() {
                return String.format("clientNumber:%s", clientNumber);
            }
       }         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse directly to array of MyClass, passing array type...

```
public MyClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        MyData[] dataArray = new Gson().fromJson(mainData, MyData[].class);        
        System.out.println(dataArray[0].getClientNumber());        
   } 
   class MyData {
       private String clientNumber;
       public String  getClientNumber() {return clientNumber;}
       public void setClientNumber(String  clientNumber) {this.clientNumber = clientNumber;}

       public String toString() {
           return String.format("clientNumber:%s", clientNumber);
       }
   }   
}
```